# Brightness issues on a Samsung N220

Tags: 11.10, brightness

I updated my Ubuntu to 11.10 a few hours ago and the screen brightness keeps going up to the maximum and down to the minimum all the time on it's own. Sometimes it stops for a few minutes. And when I try to set it myself manually or when a few minutes has passed, it starts up again.
(I'm new in trying to fix my own problems, so I might not get the obvious things right away.)

I now restarted a couple of times and now I'm using a newer version of kernel and the brightness is now constantly down and can't be set manually.

My laptop is a Samsung N220. I bought it a little over a year ago. I still have Windows 7 Starter on it (it was originally on it), but I had Ubuntu put on it from the start.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:voria/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install samsung-backlight
```

please note that in 13.04 that last command has changed to

```
sudo apt-get install samsung-tools
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution in this thread worked for me

http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/bildschirmhelligkeit-bei-gnome-3-spinnt-rum/

Comment: I had my friend take a look at my computer and he fixed it. I don't exactly know what he did.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Imagine the linked site goes down for maintenance or forever - your answer would become worthless.

Answer (score 1):

Solution can be found at [Linux on my Samsung](https://launchpad.net/~voria/+archive/ppa). I use this on my N210 and it has fixed a back-light issue I was having.  They also provide the 'Easy slow down manager' which gets the other hot keys to work.

Comment: Can you add some detail here? Did you just add the ppa and upgrade, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

The backlight flickering is caused by [bug 810093](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/810093) and affect many, if not all, Samsung netbooks running Oneiric. There are few workarounds from which at least these two work:

A) Download and install 'samsung-laptop' package from Fortunato's Linux on my Samsung [testing PPA](https://launchpad.net/~voria/+archive/archive). The fix isn't (at least it isn't mentioned in the changelog nor in the bug report) in the stable [Linux on my Samsung PPA](https://launchpad.net/~voria/+archive/ppa).

OR B) Disable the kernel module by adding:

```
blacklist samsung_laptop
```

to :

> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

and then reboot.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting this into the file */etc/rc.local*:

```
setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00
```

To set the brightness to maximum all the time. I don't know if it works for you but that did the charm for me.