# Samsung N135 Brightness won't stop cycling after 11.10 upgrade

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, brightness

I updated my netbook to 11.10 last night. This morning I find my screen will not stop cycling through the brightness setting. Fn key doesn't respond and it's actually using up all of my system resources, so I'm typing this from my phone! Any ideas?

Comment: Note for moderators: This question has already been asked in question 67262. While, the HW isn't exactly the same, it's caused by the same bug and thus has the same workarounds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Brightness issues on a Samsung N220](http://askubuntu.com/questions/67262/brightness-issues-on-a-samsung-n220)

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem with my Samsung N150 Plus on 11.04. The solution for me was to install the **Linux On My Samsung** PPA provided by Voria and install the `samsung-backlight` and `samsung-tools` packages.

- [ppa:voria/ppa [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~voria/+archive/ppa) ([Here are instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983) And [here's information on PPA safety.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out))
- [Here's a guide to the packages in this PPA.](http://www.voria.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=296)

Although the site shows 9.10 and 10.04 I wouldn't worry since I installed it on 11.04 with no issues. If you're uncertain or are having problems I'd recommend [asking on their forums](http://www.voria.org/forum).